# Google analytics on ios crashes when updating to 3.10 when value is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-analytics, crash

Since I updated Google Analytics iOS SDK to 3.10 my app crashes everytime when I try to send an event
Everything was working good until this update.

I got the "unrecognized selector send to ... NSNull isEqualToString:"
The only way I've foung to fix the problem is to send @(0) instead of nil in value field which is pretty weird.

Has someone experimented this problem?

Here is the code where that crash

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:kGAICategoryName
                                                      action:@"Action name"
                                                       label:@""
                                                       value:nil] build]];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your kGAICategoryName ? Category and Action is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not crash when we sent Value as a nil.
need to check the string value must "not nil"

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:kGAICategoryName
                                                  action:@"Action name"
                                                   label:@""
                                                   value:nil] build]];
```

add ternary operator for string which safe you from nil value see following changes in above block

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:(kGAICategoryName)?kGAICategoryName:@""
                                                  action:(kGAIActionName)?kGAIActionName:@""
                                                   label:(kGAILabelName)?kGAILabelName:@""
                                                   value:nil] build]];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I did a test with all the parameters not nil except the value parameter and it still crashes :(

Comment: Then Mr. @T Bone you should fine where actual your value going to b nil, we cant fine this by your block of code.

Comment: Sure! I talk about the parameter which is named value that takes an NSNumber it's a very weird case value:nil crashes and value:@(0) works the problem is not related to the other parameters Category, action, label

Comment: Hey if you are using **NSNumber** then it will give error...thats why your tracker going to be crash. use simple **int** value there.